# Getting running an example for node-webgl

Tags: node.js, binding, webgl, glfw

I recently installed node-webgl in node.js server.  Along with that it's dependencies node-glfw is installed automatically. I have also installed node-gyp.

However, when I try to run a program of either node-webgl or node-glfw I am facing error. Below is the error message:

```
C:\Users\z003npra>cd C:\Users\z003npra\Desktop\node\node_modules\node-webgl\examples

C:\Users\z003npra\Desktop\node\node_modules\node-webgl\examples>node wavefront.js
C:\Users\z003npra\Desktop\node\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:83
    throw e
    ^

Error: The specified module could not be found.
\\?\C:\Users\z003npra\Desktop\node\node_modules\node-webgl\build\Release\webgl.node
at Error (native)
at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:434:18)
at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
at bindings(C:\Users\z003npra\Desktop\node\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:76:44)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\z003npra\Desktop\node\node_modules\node-webg
l\lib\webgl.js:1:108)
at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)

C:\Users\z003npra\Desktop\node\node_modules\node-webgl\examples>
```

This error is similar issue faced by a person quoted in the link: https://github.com/mikeseven/node-webgl/issues/47

I tried some possible solutions mentioned here, but issue is not getting solved.

Comment: Sorry, I did not knew this thing. Won't create such problem again. I did this for othertwo questions, will revert there now.

Comment: No worries, thanks Prajwal. Don't forget to tick your answer below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working for the node.js version v4.5.0.  But not working for node.js v4.4.6.